# Passport update session isn't persisting

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to update my user session with a new name, an easy task I thought.

I'm a logged in user and in hitting a 'update' route and I've defined my own middleware to update the session:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user);
    req.login(req.body.user, function(err) {
       if (err) return next(new Error('Error updating user profile'));
       console.log('USER UPDATED *******', req.user);
       next();
    });
};
```

It took a bit of time to dig out the above code which should simply update the Passport session object. It correctly logs the previous session, and then the updated session but when I navigate to a new page after the inital response the user object is entirely lost and just returns {}.

Any ideas?

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521795/how-to-update-req-user-session-object-set-by-passportjs)

Comment: @laggingreflex this could be something. I'm only passing fields i want to update in the req.body.user. That's as far as I understood how it works... I'll try merging new into old and passing that in.

Comment: @laggingreflex that works. Can you copy your comment to an answer and I'll award the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To log in a user and persist it into session passport uses a `serialize` function which typically stores `user.id` as a cookie and a `deserialize` function which retrieves that cookie and does a `User.findById` database call to find the associated user, and if found one, that's the user object that gets stored in `req.user`.

`req.login` passes whatever you pass it as the first argument directly to `passport.serialize`, which otherwise would've typically come from a strategy, which itself would've retrieved the user object from a database call, or created one.

So when you use `req.login` you need to pass it the user object that `passport.serialize` actually would've received, so that it could store the `id` in a cookie.

In your case, you were doing `req.login(req.body.user, ...` and since `req.body.user` comes from a POST Form variable it must not have the `id` that `passport.serialize` would've stored in the cookie.

You should instead use the new values from `req.body.user` and update `req.user` itself, and then do `req.login(req.user, ...`

```
var  _ = require('lodash');
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    //using lodash merge the updated user into the cached user
    _.merge(req.user, req.body.user);

    req.login(req.user, function(err) {
       if (err) return next(new Error('Error updating user profile'));
       console.log('USER UPDATED *******', req.user);
       next();
    });
};
```