# Express: run middleware once per second

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have an express server that is running as an API, and I have a middleware loaded as such:

*app.js*

```
const lastActivity = require('./middleware/lastActivity');
app.use(lastActivity);`
```

*middleware/lastActivity.js*

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user && isDifferentDay(req.user.last_activity) {
        User.findById(req.user.id, (err, user) => {
            user.last_activity = Date.now();
            user.save((err) => {
                // also do another async call to an external service, then
                return next();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So it checks whether the last_activity date saved on the user is a different day than today, and if so updates the user (I only care about the date, not the specific timestamp). It also does an API call to an external service to manage email marketing campaigns.

The problem however is that my web app requests two resources on page load at the same time. This means the `isDifferentDay` returns true for both of them, and the user model updates twice and more importantly I do two API calls to the external service which is rate limited.

One obvious solution is to only do one request on my client at a time, but I don't really want to limit myself to that. What I want is a sort of express 'lock' which will only run the middleware once per second? Or some other solution that I can't see.

What is the best way to handle this in a express/node manner?

Thank you.

Comment: You specification of `isDifferentDay` might be wrong : two consecutive calls to it on the same page and on the same day shouldn't return both true (unless the first call is received at 23:59:59 and the next one at 0:00:00)

Comment: where do you save the updated `last_activity` in the session? i think that if you update the session (`req.user.last_activity`) right after the `if` condition, it will be OK. another thing - use `findByIdAndUpdate` instead of findById and save. much cleaner and faster.

Comment: `isDifferentDay` returns correctly because both requests run at the same time. When this function is run, it returns true for both, and continues down that path.

Comment: ah I see what you mean @Tom. If I can update the session syncronoulsy, that should work.

Comment: you can. and not **should** work, it **would** work :)

Comment: @Tom I don't save the last_activity in the session on this request, just in the database - then it refreshes req.user on the next request

Comment: I understand, that's why I said you should update it also after this condition, this would make it updated for the next request even before refreshing from the database.

Comment: @Tom do you know how to update the session? I tried setting `req.user.last_activity` and `req.session.passport.user.last_activity` but this didnt persist between requests

Comment: I don't know passportjs, you should check for answers online, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521795/how-to-update-req-user-session-object-set-by-passportjs

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a typical race condition.
Since you only care about user's `last_activity` once per day, instead of using `findById` you can add an additional filter to DB request AND update it in one go.
E.g.

```
var query = { 
    _id: req.user.id,
    last_activity: req.user.last_activity
};
User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { last_activity: Date.now() }, (err, user) => {
    if (!user)
        return; // user was changed between requests, do nothing
    // ... the rest of your code
});
```

That way, you'll only update the user if it's `last_activity` was left unchanged between your actions.